# How to avoid swipe to delete calling setEditing at the UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, swipe

I know, that when I implement `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`and `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`, a swipe-to-delete does not call `setEditing:animated:` at my `UITableViewController` (being the delegate of the `UITableView`).

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` implementation that does a little UI rearrangements when going to edit mode. I wanted to be smart and implemented these changes in `setEditing:animated:` at the table view cell implementation itself (which obviously makes sense).

However, when swiping to delete, I still get a call to `setEditing:animated:` at my table view cell implementation. And I have no parameter that tells me that I am swiping. The call stack also shows none of my own methods that would give me a chance to do something. It shows that `setEditing:animated` is called at the `UITableView`. The only thing obviously is, that it is not called at the delegate (my controller in this case).

Of course, I could set a flag at the cell in `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` that tells it that the next `setEditing` call will be for a swipe, but that does not sound like good style.

**Edit**: it doesn't even work, because it is not guaranteed that `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is called, so I cannot set the flag back.

Any ideas how to solve this issue elegantly?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. So you still want to do something in your UITableViewCell's setEditing:animated:, right? If not, does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode

Comment: I want to have swipe-to-delete enabled. But I want to be able to distinguish between "real" edit mode and the "pseudo" edit mode that is set for swipe-to-delete. In the `UITableViewDelegate` I can distinguish both, because `setEditing:animated:` is not called when swiping to delete. However I am not able to make a difference in the `UITableViewCell` implementation. Or am I somehow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think UITableViewCell's [willTransitionToState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/willTransitionToState%3a) instance method may be what you are looking for. Something like this:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        swipedToDelete = YES; // BOOL ivar
    }
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (swipedToDelete) {
        // do your stuff, or don't
    }
}
```

Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem of getting notified at the cell for a swipe. Thanks! Setting the flag back can be done in `willTransitionToState` in the else branch.But one problem remains: If I start editing in my table view, all cells get the `setEditing` call. Also, when I end editing but not in this situation: I swipe to delete getting the "Delete" button and then press "Edit" in my table view. Then the cells get no call to `setEditing`. That's really strange. Any ideas?

Comment: One note: the problem when debugging is that the `setEditing:animated:` of the cells is triggered via the `UITableViewController`'s implementation of `setEditing:animated:` (in my case a `[super setEditing:editing]`). So, I can just guess that the cells are notified, because there is one cell with `editing == YES`.

Comment: May Apple had the same problem with this in the contacts app. They "solved" it by changing the "Edit" button into a "Done" button, so there is no way into edit mode from the delete confirmation state.

Comment: If you add [super willTransitionToState:state]; in your code you preserve the common cell behavior.
Just in case someone (like me) copy and pastes this method and wonders why the icons in the cell disappeared.. ;)

Comment: As Raphael said, add 
[super willTransitionToState:state];

Answer (score 6):

I know this has probably been done to death, but the solutions presented didn't seem to be a complete simple answer, nor did they seem to provide good example code, so I thought I'd add my answer.

Add to your class a private instance variable:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController {
    BOOL _cellSwiped;
}
```

Override the setEditing method to look for the `_cellSwiped` variable and only propagate if we didn't swipe.  The part that people seem to be missing is that `_cellSwiped` needs to be reset back to NO otherwise you will never be able to use the edit button after swiping!

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!_cellSwiped) {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    } else if (!editing) {
        _cellSwiped = NO;
    }
}
```

Finally, add this method override to detect the swipe:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _cellSwiped = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What I do is something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cellSwiped = YES;
    self.editing = NO;
}
```

Then in the

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method I simply check to see if the cellSwiped ivar is set and modify the UI accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in my question. However, this does not work reliably (see Question)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I'm wondering why nobody seems to be aware of the fact that there is a [`showingDeleteConfirmation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showingDeleteConfirmation) property built right into `UITableViewCell` (since iOS 2.0):

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    BOOL reallyEditing = editing && !self.showingDeleteConfirmation;
    // [...]
}
```

No need to override `-willTransitionToState:` and manually keep track of the state.

Comment: At that point, `showingDeleteConfirmation` is actually NO and gets set somewhere after `setEditing:animated:` call.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle != UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       // add code here

    }
}
```

When called, this method will perform the following operations

```
UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,
UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,
UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert
```

If you don't want the swipe option you can set the bool variable in the delegate method

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

`willTransitionToState` will be called before

```
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:
```