# Disable Swipe-to-Delete Gesture in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to disable the 'swipe-to-delete' gesture for a row/cell in a tableView? If so, how do you do it? The cell should still be editable in EDIT mode, but the swipe-to-delete gesture should be disabled.

Comment: Is it the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's what to do:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Detemine if it's in editing mode
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

You still need `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` to animate the deletion.

This is a much cleaner solution than iBrad Apps' solution, since you can use the default `self.editButtonItem` instead of a custom button.

Link: [UITableView disable swipe to delete, but still have delete in Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight already provided this link. No point of re-posting code from another thread. Its up to the OP now since we gave him both ways to do it :)

Comment: Yup, I implemented this and it worked. I used @dasblinkenlight's link. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the cell index which doesn't want to have the Swipe to Delete gesture? The question pointed out "one cell/row to have it disabled".

Comment: @TeoC. I didn't reference the index path because according to the question, *all* rows in the table were barred from swipe-to-delete. If instead you'd like to disable some rows from all editing (including swipe-to-delete), try iBrad Apps' solution, returning a condition for the index path instead of `NO`.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. The code below will disable it.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

**Response to your comment:**

**Edit2**: My code below will work better with a custom button. If you want the default button then go to the link that @dasblinkenlight posted.

So pretty much make a button where you want the edit buttons to show and then call this method.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableview setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: The cell should still be editable in EDIT mode, but the swipe-to-delete gesture should be disabled. That's what I need.

Comment: Ok you should reword your post then. The link that @dasblinkenlight showed you should do that then.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post. Will look into @dasblinkenlight's post in a second.

Comment: Hmmm...making a button which acts like the `editButtonItem` in all ways but one seems like a bad idea, especially considering how cumbersome it can be...why do all this when there is a supported way to do what you need?

Comment: I updated my post, this is more if you want to use a custom button (maybe OP wants custom button?). I provided OP with direction if he wants to use traditional ways.

Comment: @iBradApps Thanks for the solution. I'm not using a custom button. but I understand why you may have thought that I was using one. For reasons that I rather not go into, I needed the gesture to be disabled, but cell-deletion to still be achievable in the alternate, two-step process (e.g., red accessory-icon on the left that brings up the 'delete' button onClick). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow certain cells to be swiped and deleted, here's a solution:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == yourCellIndex) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also don't forget to have this implemented in order for it to work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // do something when deleted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a Swift version:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if tableView.editing {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```