# Delete button on uitableview during quick scroll

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview

I've a horizontal scrolling UIScrollView which is page enabled. Each page has a UITableview. I've reused the table over 20 pages. Some pages have the edit functionality and some don't.
The data for each page is got from the server.

Only problem is, during a fast scroll, the table cell on which the finger swiped sometimes shows a delete button(even though its not in edit mode).Once pressed, nothing happens and it disappears.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: you want to remove the delete button or what?

Comment: yes.. i want to make sure the delete button does not come during a fast swipe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of:

[UITableView disable swipe to delete, but still have delete in Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)

Basically, you can implement this delegate method to disable the swipe-to-delete feature:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.editing)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```