# iPhone / iPad UITable Swipe to Delete Resizes / shifts Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, swipe

Is there anyway to turn off the Swipe to Delete resizing / shifting the cell?  There is a custom cell that we are using that has a UIImageView as part of the cell display.  When the swipe is done, it shifts to the left which is what we don't want.  If we turn off autosizing in the IB, then the UIImageView does not shift, but then rotate is broke (UIView will not autoresize).

There are probably other ways around this, but was wondering if one can turn off the swipe to delete shift cells.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, just to be sure.... 1) I want the swipe to delete that brings up the delete button.... 2) When the delete button is up I don't want the cell to shift / resize.  I already have a workaround(s) for this, but just wanted to know if there is a way to turn off the cell shifting with 1) enabled.  Yes or No.  If no, will have to do one of the workarounds.

Comment: Also, indent while editing is different then shifting left when the delete button is up after a swipe, correct?  I set the cell to not do the indent while editing, but the swipe for the cell still shifted left.

Comment: Assuming the answer is NO.  Going to use a different layout / workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ort11, don't touch "autosizing" (this is related to resizing when, for example, rotating - at least, that is what I think you mean). Instead, look at the UITableViewDelegate protocol. There is a method `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:`, for example. There also is a method to prevent editing for individual cells, in case you want to. All the best -

Comment: I have not tried this, but will accept as an answer.  Ended up building custom delete fade in / out button.  It also looks good.  Did find this later on also....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?
[UITableView disable swipe to delete, but still have delete in Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)

In that you can no longer swipe to delete the cell, but you can still perhaps delete the cell by hitting the edit button.

Of course - this may not help with the moving of the cell parts; when the delete button appears on the cell the contents will still shift. You can override `-(void)layoutSubviews` in your UITableViewCell, to customize how the delete button will be positioned (more here: [iPhone UITableView - Delete Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104403/iphone-uitableview-delete-button))