# Swift: How to delete with Edit button and deactivate swipe to delete?

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have added an edit button with an IBAction to the navigation bar:

```
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        editButton.title = "Edit"
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        editButton.title = "Done"
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

For removing cells I have

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        arr.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this also activates swipe to delete. How can I remove cells without implementing swip to delete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView disable swipe to delete, but still have delete in Edit mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the linked topic is regarding Objective-C and not Swift.

Comment: Both Objective-C & Swift use the same runtime & frameworks. Both use Cocoa (or Cocoa Touch in the case of iOS). Your question is more about _How do I use the UITableView?_ (Cocoa concept) than a Swift (Language) problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        arr.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```

Comment: in Swift-4 table view editing delegate method changed

Answer (score 5):

The solution (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969313/uitableview-disable-swipe-to-delete-but-still-have-delete-in-edit-mode)), translated into Swift:

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Xcode tells me `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. That error goes away, when I delete `override`. When clicking on the delete button nothing happens though. Isn't the `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method needed somewhere?

Comment: The override is needed in case you're extending from UITableViewController. If you're using a regular UIViewController you don't need the `override` (that class does not have this method, so you can't override it)

Comment: Have you set the delegate & datasource for your TableView? Can you also post all code from this ViewController?

Answer (score 2):

Swift-4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath

    }

    let action2 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "action2") { (action, indexPath) in
        // action2 item at indexPath
    }

    return [delete, action2]
}
```